# Is "Changing the behavior of an operator like + so it works with a programmer-defined type," a good definition of operator overloading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, operator-overloading, operators

In *"Think Python: How to Think Like a Computer Scientist"*, the author defines *operator overloading* as:

> Changing the behavior of an operator like + so it works with a
>   programmer-defined type.

Is this an accurate definition of it (in programming in general, and in Python in specific)? Isn't it: *"The ability to use the same operator for different operations?"* For example, in Python, we an use `+` to add to numbers, or to concatenate two sequences. Isn't this *operator overloading*? Isn't the `+` operator *overloaded* here?

Does the author means by *"the behavior of an operator"*, raising a `TypeError` because it's not implemented for the given class? Because the operator still has its behavior with other types (e.g. *strings*).

Is the definition the author wrote, a **specific type** of *operator overloading*?

Answer (score 1):

The definition given in "How to think..." is correct.
It isn't specific for Python, C++ has the same concept.

The programmer can give an operator a new meaning, e.g. adding two vectors with a + instead of two scalar numbers.

The mere fact that an operator can be used on multiple datatypes natively doesn't have a specific naming. In almost any language + can be used to add integers or floats. There's no special word for this and many programmers aren't even aware of the difference.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I had a misconception about this.